# How to send application/octet-stream data in a multipart/form-data content type using multer without filename parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multipartform-data, multer, octetstring

I have a multipart/form-data content type which I have to send over a POST request.

multipart data contains application/octet-stream, i.e array of bytes.

I am using multer node module at the server side to process the incoming multipart data.

I am using multer.any() preparser to parse the incoming data.

I am not able to get the octet stream data in req.body.content parameter where "content" is the name parameter in the request header.

req.body.content returns empty.

When I add a filename parameter to the multipart request header, such as filename="content" and send the same octet stream, I can access the octet stream via req.files parameter.

But I dont want to send a filename parameter in the request header of multipart data, since I am not sending a file and only a payload.

Do I have to use a different preprocessor other than multer.any() to get the payload in req.body rather than req.filename?

Or do I have to use a different npm module other than multer to process octet stream in multipart data

Answer (score 0):

I used `multer.single` to get this done.

Here is my code snippet from the app.js file in the node

```
import multer from 'multer';
const upload = multer();

app.post('/your_api_url', upload.single('file'),(req, res) => {
 // here req.file.buffer is the array buffer which contains the octet stream 
});
```